# Ignore one item in for ...loop Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

```
Loop Delete user
     ${fruits}  create list                locnx      huongpt1    xuanhh      lynch       
    :FOR    ${fruit}  IN    @{fruits}
       \   Log       ${fruit}
       \   go to   http://sssss.info:8080/secure/admin/user/UserBrowser.jspa
       \   input text    id= user-filter-userSearchFilter     ${fruit}
       \    Click button     id=user-filter-submit
       \     Wait Until Page Contains      ${fruit}    3
```

My ideal:
If user  exists in search result then click "Delete" button.
If user doesn't exist in search result then ignore "locnx" and continue with "huongpt1"

How I can do it ..Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
Loop Delete user 
    ${fruits}  create list  locnx huongpt1 xuanhh lynch
    :FOR ${fruit} IN @{fruits} 
        \ Log  ${fruit} 
        \ go to  http://sssss.info:8080/secure/admin/user/UserBrowser.jspa 
        \ input text  id= user-filter-userSearchFilter  ${fruit} 
        \ Click button  id=user-filter-submit 
        \ ${status}  ${value} =  Run Keyword And Return Status  Wait Until Page Contains  ${fruit}  3
        \ Run Keyword If  '${status}' == 'PASS'  keyword_to_delete
```